# Resubmitting an application

Tags: office-action

Is there any valid reason to resubmit an application that's had an unfavorable office action and abandoned several years earlier?

Comment: Was the earlier application published? If so, it makes the answer very easy indeed.

Comment: @Maca is it possible to have an OA without publishing?

Comment: @DonQuiKong Absolutely, I'd say it's common to have at least one kind of action before publication.